# How to re-render screen on click in React Native Navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-animated

I have a rectangle inside React Native Navigation screen that I want to animate every time user clicks on that specific screen. Now it only plays animation once, when application renders for the first time. I saw multiple solutions that worked for other people for this kind of a problem, but none of them worked for me - the application doesn't re-render on click. What am I doing wrong?

SettingsScreen.js (animation which needs to rerender on screen switch)

```
const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen");

const SettingsScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  return (
    <FlatList
      contentContainerStyle={style.barContainer}
      data={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
      keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
      renderItem={() => (
        <ProgressBar isFocused={isFocused} navigation={navigation} />
      )}
    ></FlatList>
  );
};

const ProgressBar = ({ navigation, isFocused }) => {
  const barWidth = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  console.log(barWidth);

  const finalWidth = width / 2;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const listener = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      Animated.spring(barWidth, {
        toValue: finalWidth,
        bounciness: 10,
        speed: 2,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start();
    });

    return listener;
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <View style={style.contentContainer}>
      <Animated.View style={[style.progressBar, { width: barWidth }]} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

MainContainer.js (where all the navigation is set up)

```
const profileName = "Profile";
const detailsName = "Details";
const settingsName = "Settings";
const profileNameFR = "P";
const detailsNameFR = "D";
const settingsNameFR = "S";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function MainContainer() {
  const { locale } = useContext(LanguageContext);
  
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;

            let rn = route.name;

            if (rn === profileName || rn === profileNameFR) {
              iconName = focused ? "person" : "person-outline";
            } else if (rn === detailsName || rn === detailsNameFR) {
              iconName = focused ? "list" : "list-outline";
            } else if (rn === settingsName || settingsNameFR) {
              iconName = focused ? "settings" : "settings-outline";
            }

            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
          tabBarActiveTintColor: "tomato",
          inactiveTintColor: "grey",
          tabBarStyle: { padding: 10, height: 60 },
          tabBarLabelStyle: { paddingBottom: 10, fontSize: 10 },
          style: { padding: 10 },
        })}
      >
```

Comment: Which version of react navigation are you using?

Comment: "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.4",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because FlatList is a PureComponent, meaning that it will not re-render if `props` remain the same. So in this case try to use `useIsFocused` hook inside the `SettingsScreen` component and pass it to `ProgressBar` as a prop.

Inside SettingsScreen:

```
const isFocused = useIsFocused();

...

<FlatList
 ...
 renderItem={() => <ProgressBar isFocused={isFocused} />}
```

Also it's not recommended to use `useIsFocused` hook because this will unnecessary re-render your component many times. Instead you can use an event listener to listen to 'focus' event, like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 const listener = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    Animated.spring(barWidth, {
      toValue: finalWidth,
      bounciness: 10,
      speed: 2,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
 });

 return listener;
}, [navigation])
```

Comment: I find it hard understanding how exactly does isFocused prop is working. Also, it re-renders the page a few times on screen change, but the value of barWidth stays the same, so it stays the same because animation is using useRef hook (as per my understanding on re-render it should be set back to 0)? Thanks for an answer but the problem for me still remains. I've updated my code on main post.

Comment: I mark this as a correct answer because this looks the right method to re-render screen on click, which actually was the primary question.